# How to include user address details in the user profile response

Tags: keycloak

I am currently using the JavaScript adapter to retrieve the profile for the currently logged in user via the `loadUserProfile()` function. Is it possible to control what properties and attributes are returned in this profile object returned?

I have some custom attributes set against the user account in my Keycloak server which I do see coming back.

I then noticed I could add a 'User Address' mapper for my client which I have added and was hoping I would see this come back in the loadUserProfile but it does not show up.

I have made sure the 'Add to userinfo' toggle button is enabled for the address mapper I have added. I assume though this option is only for when retrieving from the userinfo endpoint, not this user profile function I am calling through the JavaScript adapter.

Can I get this address field to show in the profile response, or do I have to have custom address attribute configured and set on the user in the Keycloak admin portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client mappers are meant to put (or not) user attributes into the tokens (idtoken and/or access token), if you inspect `idTokenParsed` object for instance , you will see your `address` object in there. `loadUserProfile()` just calls the user account endpoint and is unrelated to these client mappers.

Comment: Ok thanks, so does that mean there is no way to restrict what is returned back in the user profile?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible.

Comment: Ok, one more thing, now that I have enabled the User Address mapper, I can see an empty address object property returned in the userinfo response. I have set against my users attributes an address object property, e.g. `{"street_address":"1 My Street", "locality: "Cardiff"}` but these sub fields dont show up in the userinfo, just remains as an empty address property. Any ideas why this may be? Thanks

Comment: The `street_address` sub in userinfo is mapped by default with just `street`user attribute , not sure why it does not work for `locality`

Comment: Hmm ok, I wonder if there is a bug. I have set my address user attribute to `{"street":"1 My Street", "locality: "Cardiff", "region: "Cardiff", "postal_code": "CF104RA"}` but non of these come back in the address object in the userinfo response

Comment: Ok I have raised a separate question for this with screen shots on how I have setup the mapper in my keycloak server